# How do I regenerate web.config for .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

The following files are deleted accidentally:

```
web.config
web.config.comments
web.config.default
```

from

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

How do I regenerate them? Note that I did not make any manual configurations to these files after installing Visual Studio, so I'd like to recreate whatever they were before.

Comment: Copy them from another machine. Or repair/reinstall .NET

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chaim770/78734be1e3090cbd64b371e41032ed35

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chaim770/33e765accf39da72bb47ce4186860fa4

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chaim770/9654a173da0e2ab8f4ed8fb86d73ddb9

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chaim770/0052778856924474b63c02062f0ad29a